# HashMap vs ConcurrentHashMap for a threadsafe value type

Tags: multithreading, collections, concurrency

HashMap vs ConcurrentHashMap, when the value is AtomicInteger or LongAdder, is there any harm in using HashMap in a multithreaded environment ?

Comment: Your values support defined semantics for concurrent modification, but that's not going to help you when you're mutating the *map*.

Comment: So the HashMap is initialized by a thread previously and no more updates are done henceforth. In that case I guess it is safe. Your thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

An object being of type `AtomicInteger` or `LongAdder` just means that the object itself is safe in a concurrent modification operation (i.e. if two threads try to modify it, they will do so one after the other). However, if the map containing the objects itself is of type 'HashMap', then concurrent modification operations of the map are not safe. For instance, if you want to add a key-value pair only if the key doesn't already exist in the map, you cannot safely use the `putIfAbset()` operation anymore because it's not synchronized/thread-safe in `HashMap`. And if you do use it, then it is possible that two threads will execute call this method at the same time, both of them reaching the conclusion that the map doesn't have they key, and then both of them adding a key-value pair, resulting in one of them overwriting the other other's value.

Comment: So the HashMap is initialized by a thread previously and no more updates are done henceforth. In that case I guess it is safe. Your thoughts ?

Comment: Yes, in that case it should be safe to use `HashMap` since you're just reading the values and not updating them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a HashMap in a multithreaded environment. The reason is as follows:

If multiple threads operate on a simple HashMap they can **damage the internal structure of the HashMap** which is an array of linked lists. The links can go missing or go in circles. The result will be that the HashMap will be totally unusable and corrupt. This is the reason you should always use a concurrentHashMap in a multithreaded environment regardless of what value you want to store in the map itself.

Now, in a concurrentHashMap of a type say map< String val, 'any number'> 'any number' could be a LongAdder or an AtomicLong etc. Remember that not all operations on a concurrentHashMap are threadsafe by default. Therefore, if you use say a LongAdder then you could write the following atomic operation without any need to synchronize:

```
map.putIfAbsent(a string key, new LongAdder());
map.get("abc").increment();
```

Comment: The wiring of keys to values is done before hand in a single threaded fashion and never changed afterwards. I mean put operations are performed by a thread while initializing and never changed through out the lifecycle of the application